# Coin flip need help on error

Tags: java

Im writing code that is a random coinflipper that will have one person input their guess. I can't touch anything in the main as that is the directions for the assignment. I'm getting this error though when I try to run it

> Error:(15, 34) java: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.String

The error is happening in the main on this line:   `coin=flip();`   but I can't change anything in the main. Please help this is due tonight! Here is my code:

```
public class CoinFlip {

static String side = "";
static String user = "";
static String winner = "";

public static void main(String args[]) {    
    String coin;

    greeting();

    do
    {
        user=IO.getString("Would you like: (H)- Heads or (T)- Tails");
        coin=flip();
        winner=compare(user,coin);
        output(user,coin,winner);

    }while( repeat() );
}

public static void greeting() {
    System.out.println("In a second, choose heads or tails. A coin flip will show and a winner will be shown.");

}
public static void flip() {

    int random = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    if (random = 0)
        side = "H";
    else if (random = 1)
        side = "T";
}
public static void compare(String args[]) {
    if (user = side)
        winner = "Winner";
    else
        winner = "Loser";
}
public static void output() {
    System.out.println(side);
    System.out.println(winner);
}
public static void  repeat() {
    String again;
    if (again = "yes")
        main();
    else if (again = "no")
        System.out.println("Thanks for playing!");
}
}
```

Comment: `void flip()` doesn't return anything, but you're trying to assign the result to `coin` when you say `coin=flip();`. You need to make `flip()` return a `String`, or say `flip(); coin = side;`.

Comment: you are supposed to ``return`` the ``"H"`` or ``"T"``, but that's not possible with a method type of ``void``. Change ``void flip()`` to ``String flip()``.

Answer (score 3):

Change `public static void flip() {` to `public static String flip() {` and add (at the end of `flip`)

```
 return side;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method flip() should return the result either "H" or "T" based on code.
So, flip() method signature need to change from void return type to String.